# devcontainer extension caching - Current Best Practice?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, caching

[The advanced container guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/avoid-extension-reinstalls) says you should mount a volume to the extensions folder to cache the extensions, however this setting also exists:

[image]

This setting appears to mount a named /vscode volume and then symlink extensions into your .vscode-server-insiders folder.

So is the above guidance out of date and needs to be replaced with this setting or is the guidance still useful?

Answer (score 1):

Here I was wondering why the extensions keep on reinstalling. I followed the advanced devcontainer guide and mounted the extensions manually, and it seems the new vscode setting conflict with the old instruction. The old instruction is no longer needed if you use the new vscode settings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround. VSCode automatically creates `.vscode-server/` directory in `/root` inside the container. Thus, it won't install them again by mounting the extension metadata and its binary cache.

```yaml
services:
  some-service:
    image: someimage
    volumes:
      - .vscode-server/extensions/:/root/.vscode-server/extensions/
      - .vscode-server/extensionsCache/:/root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache/
```